# Find an appropriate transformation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Consider

$$-\frac{d}{dx}(p(x)y’)+q(x)y=f(x),0\le x \le 1,y’(0)=a, y’(1)=b$$
I have to transform this boundary value problem into

$$-\frac{d}{dx}(p(x)z’)+q(x)z=F(x),0\le x \le 1,z’(0)=0, z’(1)=0$$

I have spent hours on hours on this problem and still could find the right transformation.

It would be great if someone could help me with this
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the relationship between $f$ and $F$?

Comment: I guess there is no relation, I think it just means after applying transformation the RHS will change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we set

$$
z(x) := y(x) + \underbrace{\left[ (a-b) \frac{x^2}{2} -ax\right]}_{h(x)},
$$

then

- $z'(0)=y'(0)-h'(0)=a-a = 0$;
- $z'(1) = y'(1)-h'(1)=b -b = 0$.

As regards the equation:

$$
\begin{split}
-(pz')'+qz &= -(p(y+h)')' +q(y+h) \\
&=-\left(py'+ph'\right)' + qy + qh\\
&= \underbrace{-(py')'+qy}_{=f(x)} - (ph')'+qh\\
&= f(x) + q(x)h(x) -p'(x)h'(x)-p(x)h''(x)\\
&= f(x) + q(x)\left[ (a-b) \frac{x^2}{2} -ax\right] -\left[(a-b)x-a\right]p'(x)-(a-b)p(x)
\end{split}
$$
So,

$$
F(x) = f(x) + q(x)\left[ (a-b) \frac{x^2}{2} -ax\right] -\left((a-b)x-a\right)p'(x)-(a-b)p(x)
$$

---

**Example:**

As an example, if $p \equiv 1$ and $q \equiv 0$, then the initial problem

$$
\begin{cases}
y''(x) = f(x) \\
y'(0) = a\\
y'(1) = b\\
\end{cases}
$$

is transformed into

$$
\begin{cases}
z''(x) = f(x) -(a-b)\\
z'(0) = 1\\
z'(1) = 1\\
\end{cases}
$$